# Spring MVC how @RequestBody works

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I thought that `@RequestBody` tries to map request `params` to the object after the annotation by the property names.

But if I got:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person formGet(@RequestBody Person p,ModelMap model) {
    return p;
}
```

The request:

```
http://localhost:8080/proj/home/form?id=2&name=asd
```

Return 415

When I change `@RequestBody Person p` with `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params` it's OK:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person formGet(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        return new Person();
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person{
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Spring vresion `3.2.3.RELEASE`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add a default constructor to `Person`?

Comment: Just tried, didn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's a job for `@ModelAttribute`, not `@RequestBody`.

- `@ModelAttribute` populates fields of the target object with values of the corresponding request parameters, performing conversions if necessary. It can be used for requests generated by HTML forms, links with parameters, etc.
- `@RequestBody` converts requests to object using one of preconfigured `HttpMessageConverter`s. It can be used for requests containing JSON, XML, etc. However, there is no `HttpMessageConverter` that replicates behavior of `@ModelAttribute`.

Answer (score 4):

The conversion of input to a bean needs:

Use POST or PUT request for instance with JSON body.
It is also good to specify expected content tipe by "consumes" in Request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json" )
```

Add an instance of converter that implements HttpMessageConverter to the servlet context (servlet.xml for instance)

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" 
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
<property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

Add jackson core and mapper jars to classpath (or to pom.xml)

then you can try it using curl

```
 curl -X POST  http://localhost:8080/proj/home/form -d '{"name":"asd", "id": 2}' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Sorry for missing details but I hope that it helps